# TERADATA Query for entire month

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I wanted to know if there was a way to extract data from a date column pertaining to an entire month.

SEL * FROM DB.TBLNAME TABLE
WHERE TABLE.DATE_ BETWEEN  DATE '01-02-2022' AND DATE ' 28-02-2022'

So in the above query(wrote it here as an example so hope i didnt make any typo mistake) im searching for all dates from the 1st to the 28th of february but wanted to know if there was a more elegant method as to select a month match eg. 02-2022.

I hope my question was detailed enough.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I guess,it is the best available method

Comment: Specifying BETWEEN a starting and ending date (which should be DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd' format) is sometimes most efficient. Another common option is to select a list of dates from a calendar table and join to that. One could also apply a datetime function to the table column that returns one value per month, such as td_month_begin or MonthNumber_of_Calendar or even CAST/TO_CHAR to create a string that includes only year and month -  but then that function would need to be evaluated for every row in the table to apply the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could do something like this to make it easier to develop and change as you would need it

```
SELECT
     *
FROM DB.TBLNAME TABLE
WHERE 1=1
     AND MONTH(TABLE.DATE) = 2
     AND YEAR(TABLE.DATE) = 2022
```

This is how I would normally do it as you would then be able to write a python script to go with it or a param to dynamically pull the data you need for the month/year